# how to pass null value as a datetime to sql server (DAL Layer)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, null, nullable

i have got a column (nullable but it is Datetime)in sql server ..

if user is not selected any date i need to pass the null value for this field for that purpose I have done like this below

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime expiryDate;
        DateTime? expDate = null;
         if (chkExpDate.Checked == true)
        {
            expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtExpiryDate.Text);
        }
        else if (expDate.HasValue)
        {
            expiryDate = expDate.Value;
        }
        else
            expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DBNull.Value);
         // here I am getting error like "object cannot be cast from DBNULL or value
```

what i need to do if i have to overcome this problem .. I need to pass null value if user is not selected any date how can i do this..

would any one please help on this.. Many thanks

DAL for this

```
public bool ReAssignLicense(string certificateID, string serialNumber, string newEmail, string ticketID, string backupBy, string customerName, DateTime expDate)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> ParaList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@certificate", certificateID));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@certSN", serialNumber));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@newemail", newEmail));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@ticket", ticketID));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@bkpBy", backupBy));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_name", customerName));
        ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@exp_date", expDate));

        return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString),CommandType.StoredProcedure,"sp_Update",ParaList.ToArray()) > 0;
    }
```

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the query that receives the parameters. If they end up in a `WHERE` clause you have no other option than to rewrite the query into something like `WHERE dateField IS NULL`. A comparison like  `WHERE dateField = @param` is undetermined in SQL when the parameter value is null, and hence doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime? expDate = null;
  if (chkExpDate.Checked == true)
  {
    expDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtExpiryDate.Text);
  }
```

I set your DateTime variable here to nullable.

```
public bool ReAssignLicense(string certificateID, string serialNumber, string newEmail, string ticketID, string backupBy, string customerName, DateTime? expDate)
{
  List<SqlParameter> ParaList = new List<SqlParameter>();
  ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@certificate", certificateID));
  ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@certSN", serialNumber));
  ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@newemail", newEmail));
  ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@ticket", ticketID));
  ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@bkpBy", backupBy));
  ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_name", customerName));

  if (expDate != null)
    ParaList.Add(new SqlParameter("@exp_date", expDate));

  return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_Update", ParaList.ToArray()) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SqlParameter moFrom1Param = new SqlParameter("@MoFrom1", expairydate == null 
           ? DBNull.Value : expairydate);
            moFrom1Param.IsNullable = true;
            moFrom1Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            moFrom1Param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(moFrom1Param);
```

---

You can make your DatTime variable as nullable variable that will handle your issue without doing anything.

as your expiryDate is nullable filed you can pass thsi filed directly in sql command or query you are calling form the dabase layer.

you can change this line like this

```
expiryDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

---

Check this post : http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-minvalue

```
//
    // This won't compile!
    //
    // DateTime dateTime1 = null;
    //
    // This is the best way to null out the DateTime.
    //
    DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: dateTime field in sql server is null so . i can insert null also .. but sorry i cannot insert the minvalue

Comment: as you are having nullable field you can do this directly pass expiryDate  in sql parameter...

Comment: i cannot pass mindate also because it is expiry date .... i cannot put any date as i need to pass null only or user selected date ..... how can i do this .....

Comment: if your expDate is null don't pass the parameter, because your datetime field in sql is null

Comment: do u mean if the user is not selected the date need not to pass from front end ... so we can do modification in DAL right ...(i.e setting null value in DAL Layer)

Comment: @pratapk - check my one more update how you can acheive thigns

Comment: @PranayRana many thanks but what about in button click .. if the user has not selected the date still i need to pass empty string right (including conversion also from string to datetime from presentation layer .... how can i handle this sitiuation at here .. if       (chkExpDate.Checked == true)
            {
                expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtExpiryDate.Text);
            }

Comment: @pratapk - i dont know your full implementation but you can do code accoding to it ....I sugges if user not selecting any value of date than you pass null not empty string because again emptry string is not compitable with DateTime and also you created nullable datetime than there is no harm in passing null value

Comment: @PranayRana thanks my problem is that only how to pass null value as datetime from frontend to DAL just code snippet is enough if you have...

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server` just insert `NULL` in the Datetime column:

```
INSERT INTO Table(name, datetimeColumn, ...)
VALUES('foo bar', NULL, ..);
```

Or, you can make use of the [DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) constaints:

```
...
DateTimeColumn DateTime DEFAULT NULL,
...
```

Then you can ignore it completely in the `INSERT` statemnt and it will be inserted withe the `NULL` value:

```
INSERT INTO Table(name, ...)
VALUES('foo bar', ..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If I understood your problem correctly then you ant to set expiryDate as null in last condition.

For the same you will be required to change the variable declaration
 DateTime expiryDate as nullable type same you did for  DateTime? expDate = null;

So your revised syntax as posted above will be as follows

```
        DateTime? expiryDate;
        DateTime? expDate = null;
        if (chkExpDate.Checked == true)
        {
            expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtExpiryDate.Text);
        }
        else if (expDate.HasValue)
        {
            expiryDate = expDate.Value;
        }
        else

            expiryDate = null;
```

Hope that will work for you.